# Java unwanted listener call and function parameeters inverted

Tags: java, function, properties, listener, call

Trying to make a circles diagram software.
Changing the circles components with a mouse dragging event.

Got 2 problems:

1)- centerXProperty's listener of sg is called however its X coordinate didn't change, how come ?

2)- I'm giving the same parameeters in the updateComponents(), however once i print some descriptions about the circles, it appears in the console that the parameeters have been inverted for centerXProperty listener.

here the code and the console prints for more details:

```
public class TDGAPIUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws NoSommet2DException, RelationMismatchException {
        Sommet sommetA = new Sommet("A");
        Sommet sommetB = new Sommet("B");

        ArcPondere e1 = new ArcPondere("e1", 5, sommetA, sommetB);

        Sommet2D  sommet2DA = new Sommet2D(sommetA);
        Sommet2D sommet2DB = new Sommet2D(sommetB);

        Relation2D relation2De1 = new Relation2D(e1);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
                  root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
                  root.getChildren().addAll(relation2De1);
                  root.getChildren().addAll(sommet2DA,sommet2DB);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Sommet implements Comparable{

    private SimpleObjectProperty<ArrayList<Relation>> listeRelations = new SimpleObjectProperty<ArrayList<Relation>>(new ArrayList<Relation>());
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet2D> sommet2D = new SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet2D>(null);
    private SimpleStringProperty label = new SimpleStringProperty("No Label");

    public Sommet(String label){
        this.label.set(label);
    }

    public Sommet(String label,Relation ... relations){
        this.label.set(label);
        this.listeRelations.getValue().addAll(Arrays.asList(relations));
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty labelProperty(){
        return this.label;
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<ArrayList<Relation>> listeRelationsProperty(){
        return this.listeRelations;
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet2D> sommet2DProperty(){
        return this.sommet2D;
    }

    /**
     * @return the label
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param label the label to set
     */
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label.setValue(label);
    }

    /**
     * @return the listeRelations
     */
    public ArrayList<Relation> getListeRelations() {
        return listeRelations.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param listeRelations the listeRelations to set
     */
    public void setListeRelations(ArrayList<Relation> listeRelations) {
        this.listeRelations.setValue(listeRelations);
    }

    public Sommet2D getSommet2D(){
        return this.sommet2D.get();
    }

    public void setSommet2D(Sommet2D sommet2D){
        this.sommet2D.setValue(sommet2D);
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString(){
        return "Description du Sommet: " + this.label.getValue() + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Sommet)
            return this.label.getValue().equals(((Sommet) o).getLabel());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Sommet)
            return this.label.getValue().compareTo(((Sommet) o).label.getValue());
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean isIncidentTo(Relation relation){
        for(Relation r: this.listeRelations.getValue())
            if(relation.equals(r)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ArcPondere extends Arc {     
    public ArcPondere(String label, double poid, Sommet sommetGauche, Sommet sommetDroit) {
        super(label, sommetGauche, sommetDroit);
        this.ponderationValue.setValue(new ValuePonderation(poid));
    }

    /**
     * @return the poid
     */
    public double getPoid() {
        return this.ponderationValue.getValue().getPoid();
    }

    /**
     * @param poid the poid to set
     */
    public void setPoid(double poid) {
        this.ponderationValue.getValue().setPoid(poid);
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty poidProperty(){
        return this.ponderationValue.getValue().poidProperty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof ArcPondere)
            return super.equals(o) && this.ponderationValue.getValue().getPoid() == ((ArcPondere) o).ponderationValue
                    .getValue().getPoid();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o){
        if(o instanceof ArcPondere)
            return (int)(this.getPoid() - ((ArcPondere) o).getPoid());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Sommet2D extends Circle {

    private SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet> sommet = new SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet>(null);
    private Text label = new Text();

    public Sommet2D(Sommet sommet){
        this.sommet.setValue(sommet);
        this.sommet.getValue().setSommet2D(this);

        this.initGraphicSettings(
                  "-fx-fill: rgb(255,255,255); "
                + "-fx-stroke-width: 2px; "
                + "-fx-stroke: rgba(0,0,0,1);",
                  "-fx-fill: rgb(0,0,0);");

        this.setRadius(25.0);
        this.setCenterX(Screen.getMainScreen().getWidth()/2);
        this.setCenterY(Screen.getMainScreen().getHeight()/2);

        this.layoutXProperty().addListener((observable) -> { this.setLayoutX(0.0); });
        this.layoutYProperty().addListener((observable) -> { this.setLayoutY(0.0); });

        this.label.textProperty().bind(sommet.labelProperty());
        this.label.layoutXProperty().addListener((observable) -> { this.label.setLayoutX(0.0); });
        this.label.layoutYProperty().addListener((observable) -> { this.label.setLayoutY(0.0); });
        this.label.xProperty().bind(this.centerXProperty().subtract(this.label.prefWidth(0) / 2));
        this.label.yProperty().bind(this.centerYProperty().add(this.label.prefHeight(0)/4));

        this.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {     
                double xPos = event.getSceneX();
                double yPos = event.getSceneY();

                setCenterX(xPos);
                setCenterY(yPos);
            }            
        });

        this.parentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Parent>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Parent> observable, Parent oldValue, Parent newValue) {
                if(newValue != null){
                    if(label.getParent() != null)
                        (((Pane)label.getParent()).getChildren()).remove(label);
                    (((Pane)newValue).getChildren()).add(label);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setSommet(Sommet sommet){
        this.sommet.setValue(sommet);
    }

    public Sommet getSommet(){
        return this.sommet.getValue();
    }

    public void initGraphicSettings(String circleCss,String labelCss){    
        this.label.setStyle(labelCss);
        this.setStyle(circleCss);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Relation2D extends Line{

    private SimpleObjectProperty<Relation> relation = new SimpleObjectProperty<Relation>(null);
    private Line[] arrows = new Line[2];
    private Text label = new Text();

    public Relation2D(Relation relation) throws NoSommet2DException {
        Sommet2D sg = relation.getSommetGauche().getSommet2D();
        Sommet2D sd = relation.getSommetDroit().getSommet2D();

        if(sd == null || sg == null) 
            throw new NoSommet2DException();

        this.relation.setValue(relation);        

        this.initLabelBindings();
        this.initComponentsBindings();
        this.initParentBindings();
        this.initGraphicSettings("-fx-fill: rgb(255,255,255); -fx-stroke-width: 5px; -fx-stroke: rgba(0,0,0,1);",
                "-fx-fill: rgb(0,0,0);");

        if(relation instanceof Arc)
            this.initArrows();
    }

    public void setSommet(Relation relation){
        this.relation.setValue(relation);
    }

    public Relation getRelation(){
        return this.relation.getValue();
    }

    public void initGraphicSettings(String lineCss,String labelCss){
        this.setStyle(labelCss);
        this.label.setStyle(labelCss);
    }

    private void initLabelBindings(){
        this.label.setX(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        this.label.setY(Double.MIN_VALUE);

        Relation relation = this.getRelation();

        this.label.textProperty().bind(relation.labelProperty().concat(
            (relation instanceof AretePondere ? ": " + ((AretePondere) relation).getPoid() : (
                    relation instanceof ArcPondere ? ": " + ((ArcPondere) relation).getPoid() : ""))));

        this.label.layoutXProperty().addListener(event -> this.setLayoutX(0.0));
        this.label.layoutYProperty().addListener(event -> this.setLayoutY(0.0));

        this.label.layoutXProperty().addListener(event -> this.label.setLayoutX(0.0));
        this.label.layoutYProperty().addListener(event -> this.label.setLayoutY(0.0));

        this.label.xProperty().bind((this.startXProperty().add((this.endXProperty().subtract(this.startXProperty())).divide(2))).subtract(this.label.getText().length() * 7/2 * this.label.getStrokeWidth()));
        this.label.yProperty().bind((this.startYProperty().add((this.endYProperty().subtract(this.startYProperty())).divide(2))).subtract(this.label.getText().length() * this.label.getStrokeWidth()));
    }

    private void initComponentsBindings(){
        // Layout ne doit pas influencer les composantes des vecteurs         
        this.layoutXProperty().addListener(event -> this.setLayoutX(0.0));
        this.layoutYProperty().addListener(event -> this.setLayoutY(0.0));
        //
        this.setStartX(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        this.setEndX(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        this.setStartY(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        this.setEndY(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        Sommet2D sg = this.getRelation().getSommetGauche().getSommet2D();
        Sommet2D sd = this.getRelation().getSommetDroit().getSommet2D();

        DoubleBinding dx = sd.centerXProperty().subtract(sg.centerXProperty());
        DoubleBinding dy = sd.centerYProperty().subtract(sg.centerYProperty());

        sg.centerXProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
            System.out.println("SG X Event:");
            updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd);
            //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        });
        sg.centerYProperty().addListener((value) -> {
            System.out.println("SG Y Event:");
            updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd); 
            //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        });

        sd.centerXProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
            System.out.println("SD X Event:");    
            updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd);
            //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        });
        sd.centerYProperty().addListener((observable) -> { 
            System.out.println("SD Y Event:");
            updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd); 
            //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        });
    }

    private void initParentBindings(){        
        this.parentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Parent>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Parent> observable, Parent oldValue, Parent newValue) {
                if(newValue != null){
                    if(label.getParent() != null) 
                        (((Pane)label.getParent()).getChildren()).removeAll(label);
                    (((Pane)newValue).getChildren()).addAll(label);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private synchronized void updateComponents(double dx, double dy, Sommet2D sg, Sommet2D sd){

        double x1 = sg.getCenterX();
        double y1 = sg.getCenterY();

        double x2 = sd.getCenterX();
        double y2 = sd.getCenterY();

        System.out.println("SG: " + sg);
        System.out.println("SD: " + sd);

        double newModule = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        double cosAlpha = (x2 - x1) / newModule;
        double alpha = Math.acos(cosAlpha);
        double sinAlpha = Math.sin(alpha);

        double r1x = cosAlpha * sg.getRadius();
        double r1y = sinAlpha * Math.signum(dy) * sg.getRadius();

        double r2x = cosAlpha * sd.getRadius();
        double r2y = sinAlpha * Math.signum(dy) * sd.getRadius();

        this.setStartX(x1 + r1x);
        this.setStartY(y1 + r1y);
        this.setEndX(x2 - r2x);
        this.setEndY(y2 - r2y);
    }

    private synchronized void initArrows(){

        this.arrows[0] = new Line();
        this.arrows[1] = new Line();

        this.arrows[0].layoutXProperty().addListener(event -> this.arrows[0].setLayoutX(0.0));
        this.arrows[0].layoutYProperty().addListener(event -> this.arrows[0].setLayoutY(0.0));
        this.arrows[1].layoutXProperty().addListener(event -> this.arrows[1].setLayoutX(0.0));
        this.arrows[1].layoutYProperty().addListener(event -> this.arrows[1].setLayoutY(0.0));

        this.arrows[0].setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#FF0000"));
        this.arrows[1].setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#0000FF"));

        this.parentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Parent>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Parent> observable, Parent oldValue, Parent newValue) {
                if(newValue != null){
                    if(arrows[0].getParent() != null)
                        (((Pane)arrows[0].getParent()).getChildren()).removeAll(arrows[0]);
                    if(arrows[1].getParent() != null)
                        (((Pane)arrows[1].getParent()).getChildren()).removeAll(arrows[1]);
                    (((Pane)newValue).getChildren()).addAll(arrows[0]);
                    (((Pane)newValue).getChildren()).addAll(arrows[1]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private synchronized void updateArrowsComponents(double dx, double dy){

        this.arrows[0].setEndX(this.getEndX());
        this.arrows[0].setEndY(this.getEndY());
        this.arrows[1].setEndX(this.getEndX());
        this.arrows[1].setEndY(this.getEndY());

        final double h = 0.5;
        final double d = 25;

        double[] lineVector = new double[]{
            1, (this.getEndY() - this.getStartY()) / (this.getEndX() - this.getStartX())
        };

        double[] wVector = new double[]{
            - Math.signum(dy) * lineVector[1] * h / Math.sqrt(lineVector[1] * lineVector[1] + 1),
            Math.signum(dy) * h / Math.sqrt(lineVector[1] * lineVector[1] + 1),
        };

        double[] wPrVector = new double[]{
            -wVector[0], -wVector[1]
        };

        double[] uwVector = new double[]{
            wVector[0] - lineVector[0],
            wVector[1] - lineVector[1]
        };

        double[] uwPrVector = new double[]{
            wPrVector[0] - lineVector[0],
            wPrVector[1] - lineVector[1]
        };

        //System.out.println("wVector: " + Arrays.toString(wVector));
        //System.out.println("wPrVector: " + Arrays.toString(wPrVector));


        //System.out.println("EndX: " + this.getEndX());
        double Xp = this.getEndX() - d * Math.signum(dx) * Math.cos(Math.atan(h/d));

        double Yp = lineVector[1] * Xp + (this.getEndY() - lineVector[1] * Xp);
        //System.out.println("P(X,Y) = (" + Xp + "," + Yp + ")");

        double Xw = (this.getEndY() - Yp + (wVector[1]/wVector[0]) * Xp - (uwVector[1]/uwVector[0]) * this.getEndX()) / (
                (wVector[1]/wVector[0]) - (uwVector[1]/uwVector[0])); 

        double XwPr = (this.getEndY() - Yp + (wPrVector[1]/wPrVector[0]) * Xp - (uwPrVector[1]/uwPrVector[0]) * this.getEndX()) / (
                (wPrVector[1]/wPrVector[0]) - (uwPrVector[1]/uwPrVector[0])); 

        double Yw = (wVector[1]/wVector[0]) * Xw + Yp - (wVector[1]/wVector[0]) * Xp;
        double YwPr = (wPrVector[1]/wPrVector[0]) * XwPr + Yp - (wPrVector[1]/wPrVector[0]) * Xp;

        this.arrows[0].setStartX(Xw);
        this.arrows[0].setStartY(Yw);

        this.arrows[1].setStartX(XwPr);
        this.arrows[1].setStartY(YwPr);
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Relation implements Comparable {

    private SimpleStringProperty label = new SimpleStringProperty("No Label");
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet> sommetGauche = new SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet>(null),
                                         sommetDroit = new SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet>(null);
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Relation2D> relation2D = new SimpleObjectProperty<Relation2D>(null);
    protected SimpleObjectProperty<ComportementPonderation> ponderationValue = new SimpleObjectProperty<ComportementPonderation>(
        new NoPonderation());

    public Relation(String label, Sommet sommetGauche, Sommet sommetDroit){
        this.label.set(label);
        this.sommetGauche.setValue(sommetGauche);
        this.sommetDroit.setValue(sommetDroit);

        this.sommetDroit.getValue().getListeRelations().add(this);
        this.sommetGauche.getValue().getListeRelations().add(this);
    }

    /**
     * @return the label
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param label the label to set
     */
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label.setValue(label);
    }

    /**
     * @return the sommetGauche
     */
    public Sommet getSommetGauche() {
        return sommetGauche.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param sommetGauche the sommetGauche to set
     */
    public void setSommetGauche(Sommet sommetGauche) {
        this.sommetGauche.setValue(sommetGauche);
    }

    /**
     * @return the sommetDroit
     */
    public Sommet getSommetDroit() {
        return sommetDroit.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * @param sommetDroit the sommetDroit to set
     */
    public void setSommetDroit(Sommet sommetDroit) {
        this.sommetDroit.setValue(sommetDroit);
    }

    public void setRelation2D(Relation2D relation2D){
        this.relation2D.setValue(relation2D);
    }

    public Relation2D getRelation2D(){
        return this.relation2D.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return (int)(this.label.getValue().compareTo(((Relation)o).getLabel())); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Relation)
            return this.label.getValue().equals(((Relation) o).getLabel());
        return false;
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet> sommetGaucheProperty(){
        return this.sommetGauche;
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Sommet> sommetDroitProperty(){
        return this.sommetDroit;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty labelProperty(){
        return this.label;
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Relation2D> relation2DProperty(){
        return this.relation2D;
    }

    public boolean isIncidentTo(Sommet sommet){
        return (this.sommetDroit.getValue().equals(sommet) || this.sommetGauche.getValue().equals(sommet));
    }    

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Description de l'arete: " + this.label.getValue() + "\n"
                + "Sommet Gauche: " + this.sommetGauche.getValue().getLabel() + "\n" 
                + "Sommet Droit: " + this.sommetDroit.getValue().getLabel() + "\n";
    }

    public ComportementPonderation getPonderation(){
        return this.ponderationValue.getValue();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ValuePonderation implements ComportementPonderation{

    private SimpleDoubleProperty ponderationValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);

    public ValuePonderation(double value){
        this.setPoid(value);
    }
    @Override
    public double getPoid() {
        return this.ponderationValue.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPoid(double poid) {
        this.ponderationValue.setValue(poid);
    }   

    @Override
    public SimpleDoubleProperty poidProperty() {
        return this.ponderationValue;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface ComportementPonderation {
    public abstract double getPoid();
    public abstract void setPoid(double poid);
    public abstract SimpleDoubleProperty poidProperty();
}
```

Some of the console prints:

```
SD X Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=694.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
---------------------------------------------
SG X Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=694.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0x000000ff]
---------------------------------------------
SD Y Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=694.0, centerY=380.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
---------------------------------------------
SG Y Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=694.0, centerY=380.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0x000000ff]
---------------------------------------------
SD X Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=410.0, centerY=380.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
---------------------------------------------
SG X Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=410.0, centerY=380.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0x000000ff]
---------------------------------------------
SD Y Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=410.0, centerY=235.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
---------------------------------------------
SG Y Event:
SG: Circle[centerX=410.0, centerY=235.0, radius=25.0, fill=0xffffffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
SD: Circle[centerX=683.0, centerY=384.0, radius=25.0, fill=0x000000ff]
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I don't know what was the problem, but mooved the same project from my laptop to my desktop computer and everything works fine.

But still wonder why it was acting that weird...

For those who encounter illogical problems, i suggest to change project to another computer, may be useful...

Answer (score 0):

One potential error I noticed:

`dy` is used twice and `dx` is never used.

```
public class Relation2D extends Line{
    ...
    private synchronized void updateComponents(double dx, double dy, Sommet2D sg, Sommet2D sd){
        ...
        double r1x = cosAlpha * sg.getRadius();
        double r1y = sinAlpha * Math.signum(dy) * sg.getRadius();

        double r2x = cosAlpha * sd.getRadius();
        double r2y = sinAlpha * Math.signum(dy) * sd.getRadius();
        ...
    }
}
```

This is likely due to a copy/paste error, it's pretty common. Turning on compiler warnings can help catch errors like this. In this case a warning for unused method parameters would have warned that `dx` is not being used.

In Eclipse to set this compiler warning go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Unnecessary code -> Value of method parameter is not used [set to Warning]`

Related to the listener, I noticed that `value` is not like the other `observable`s:

```
sg.centerXProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
    System.out.println("SG X Event:");
    updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd);
    //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
});
// ### 'value' is the only different one, I'm not sure if it's important ###
sg.centerYProperty().addListener((value) -> {
    System.out.println("SG Y Event:");
    updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd); 
    //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
});

sd.centerXProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
    System.out.println("SD X Event:");    
    updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd);
    //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
});
sd.centerYProperty().addListener((observable) -> { 
    System.out.println("SD Y Event:");
    updateComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue(),sg,sd); 
    //updateArrowsComponents(dx.getValue(),dy.getValue());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
});
```

Also, to me it seems like it's the Sommet **Gauche** X/Y Events (not the Sommet Gauche/Droit **X** Events) that have gauche (left) centerX greater than droit (right) centerX.

Comment: Thanks but i'm aware about the fact that dx isn't used. I'm expecting to use it for some other purposes later and till now i need only dy.

The 2 parameeters sg and sd are interchanged by the caller when i call it from sg's x property listener and sd's x property listener. Check the result for more details.

And why is the listener event of x property of sg firing even if it didn't change at all (using the drag event)

Comment: @Mouley I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is. I think I've figured out the french but I don't understand the significance of the output. And it is a bit difficult to understand what is going on in the code. Could you add comments (preferably in English) to briefly explain the methods. Also I noticed another thing that looks like it could be incorrect which I am adding to my answer..

Comment: there is 2 issues:
Issue a: in the output you can see from the 2 first blocks that Event " SD X Event " and " SG X Event " are fired, however in my program i'm changing only the coordinates of the SD circle. why is the second event firing ?
Issue b: i'm calling the method updateComponents with same parameeters in each listener, however the 2 last parameeters are exchanged, look at the circles descriptions of the 2 first output blocks
Sorry for the french, if more information are needed tell me

Comment: @Mouley This is certainly a tricky one. In order to help debug could you post enough code for this to be runnable (Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example please) so I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: yes sure i'll edit my post again, sorry for late answer.

Comment: done if i forgot something tell me and thanks in advance

Comment: @Mouley Sorry, I still have compile errors. Perhaps it would be best if you dump the source files somewhere rather than pasting it here.

Comment: sure , here's a link to the project i uploaded => https://files.fm/u/jt6ffggf#_ , it's a netbeans project !